# How to implement formatting bar above edittext's keyboard?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am working on a text editor . I have implemented all the functionality with buttons . I want to implement a sort of bar above edittext's keyboard which only appears when that particular edittext has the focus . Many apps on play store do offer such a user interface .

see image ( i am talking about the bar which shows **B** , *I* , etc... )
[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to add a view (horizontal bar with buttons) and set property `layout-gravity` as `bottom`. Keep it's `visibility` as `gone` and then, once the edittext gets focused you can change the `visibility` to `visible`.

The default behavior of the keyboard will push the view to the top of it.

Comment: So you need to be spoon feeded

Comment: everyone's a beginner once and I wouldn't use the word spoon feeding for someone who was unable to find a solution online. I'm sure you understand that posting a question takes more time and effort than simply searching on google !